# Batch removing subtitles using MKVToolNix

Tags: shell-script, video-subtitles

I need to batch remove all subtitles from [MKV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) files in a directory, using [MKVToolNix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKVToolNix), for one file I figured:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv --no-subtitles input.mkv
```

How do I achieve this for 100+ files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they're all in the same directory, you can do:

```
for file in *mkv; do
    mkvmerge -o "${file%.mkv}".nosubs.mkv --no-subtitles "$file"
done
```