# is there a way to extract embedded or muxed subtitles in an mkv media file without harming the media file

Tags: command-line, video-subtitles, mkv, mkvtoolnix

I have a media file which has an embedded subtitle file with it. I want the subtitle to be extracted or to be more precise a copy of the subtitle which is embedded in the media file. There are some timing issues. How do I do this ? I did see [Batch removing subtitles using MKVToolNix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328062/batch-removing-subtitles-using-mkvtoolnix) but as can be seen that changes the media file. In my case, I do not want to make any change in the original file. Changing the file will change the hash or checksum and I want to keep file integrity as it is. I tried to see if there is a manpage for

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkvmerge mkvmerge -o subs.mkv --no-audio --no-video in.mkv

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/583393/how-to-extract-subtitle-from-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: @user1133275 the comment is incorrect, as the output you are giving is an .mkv file. The output should be an .srt file. You are on the right path but need to probably modify your answer a bit and put it as an answer rather than a comment. The link you shared is good though.